# disable ssl verification on gem active_rest_client

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, faraday, active-rest-client

I'm creating a model in Ruby/rails that uses the gem "active-rest_client" (https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client). However my target server only 'speaks' HTTPS with a mismatched SSL cert. So I need to disable SSL verification when I query it (long story, just accept that).

The gem doesn't seem to have a native way to disable SSL verification. However, it relies on the faraday gem that can disable SSL verification (https://gist.github.com/mislav/938183).

When I do:

```
ActiveRestClient::Base.faraday_config do |faraday|
  faraday.ssl = false
end
```

It tells me that "ssl" is an undefined method.

Does anyone know a way?

Thanks for the help in advance!